# javascript: onclick go to specific div

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm trying to create a "diagram" with divs. If user click on next it will show the next div and so on (this is done), but the thing i'm trying to reach is, sometimes some divs will have a question with "yes" or "no" buttons, and those buttons will target to some specific div.

Ex: Div 1 - Are you ok ? Yes - Go to Div 2 | No - Go to Div 3.

Is there a way to make this dynamic ? All divs have an ID.

Here's the code i've got so far.

HTML

```
 <div id="main">   
  <h3 class="despistes">Some Title</h3>
      <div class="info" id="1" style="display:block">Div 1</div>
      <div class="info" id="2">Div 2</div>
      <div class="info" id="3">Div 3</div>
      <div class="info" id="4">Div 4</div>
      <div class="info" id="5">Div 5</div>
      <div class="info" id="6">Div 6</div>
      <div class="info" id="7">Div 7</div>
      <div class="info" id="8">Div 8</div>

 <button class="button" onclick="mostraDiv('inicio')" style="float:left">inicio</button>
 <button class="button" onclick="mostraDiv('avancar')" style="float:right">seguinte</button>
 <button class="button" onclick="mostraDiv('anterior')" style="float:right">retroceder</button>

</div>
```

JS

```
var divNo = 0;
function mostraDiv(direction) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
  switch (direction) {
    case 'inicio' : divNo = 0; break;
    case 'anterior' : divNo--;   break;
    case 'avancar' : divNo++;   break;
    case 'ultima' : divNo = sel.length-1; break;

  }
  if (divNo > sel.length-1) { divNo = 0; }
  else { if (divNo < 0) { divNo = sel.length-1; } }
  sel[divNo].style.display = 'block';
}

onload = function() {
  mostraDiv('s');
};
```

This function i found here and works fine for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what your question is here...

Comment: Do you have an online version or a screenshot ? It could help to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Why use JS for this at all? Why not use anchor tags and refer to a div id that way?  e.g. '<a href='#div2'>Go to div 2</a>'

Comment: @Paul The divs are all hidden and only appear when the user click next/back or yes or no.

Comment: @lonesomeday trying to do this http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/7665/6cke.png

Comment: @Emilie trying to do this http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/7665/6cke.png

Comment: @user2947711 I hope that image makes sense in your head. I promise you it makes none in mine.

Comment: @lonesomeday The lines are the yes or no options, my bad if i can't explain better.

Comment: You can first `display: block;` the `<div>` you want to go (or make it visible the way you want) and then use anchor to go to it like Paul said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<p>Are You OK ?</p>
<button class="button" onclick="goToDiv(2)" style="float:left">Yes</button>
<button class="button" onclick="goToDiv(3)" style="float:left">No</button>

function goToDiv(divNo) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
  if (divNo > sel.length-1) { divNo = 0; }
  else { if (divNo < 0) { divNo = sel.length-1; } }
  sel[divNo].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, i've tried that and that's ok. But i think i will have like 50 or more divs and with that it can be confused to put the target divs on the buttons. It's possible to have something more dynamic ? Perhaps i will have to try a different approach.